# Current calculation - basic circuit

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-design, ohms-law

I’m just starting off, and I’m watching a series of videos about the basics of electric circuits.

https://youtu.be/lf0lMDZVwTI

As you can see in the the picture, the teacher solved the current of the entire circuit (or at least that what I understood)

[image: screenshot of the video]

But I didn’t understand what is exactly happening between the power source and point A, can we say the current is 2A because we have calculated it with the resistance or is it same as the battery 10A, since 10A=10V/1Ω.

Maybe my question is more of: Does the current only applies after point B? Or does it apply on the whole circuit?

If it applies only after point B does that mean it’s 10Amps before point A as the previous calculation?

Very silly question, but I’m confused.

What part of the circuit did he calculate the current for?

PS: I didn’t know what tags should I use, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe my question is more of: Does the current only applies after
> point B? Or does it apply on the whole circuit?

It applies in the whole circuit. Since the circuit has no branches (It does not "split"), the same current flows from everywhere.

If you had something like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiQZyY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From A to B, current is the same (2 Amps), between B and C it splits in two (1 Amp on R1, 1 Amp on R2), and from C to D is again, the same (2 Amps).

Comment: Fantastic, it’s good to know it splits when we have branches, this complete the answers I had.

Answer (score 0):

In elementary circuits, lines between components are assumed to have zero resistance thus making point A identical to the + point of the power supply. In real circuits, you may need to consider the resistance of the wiring. That would mean adding a resistor to represent some wires (usually only rather long ones). There are tables and online calculators that help determine wire resistance.

The current can not change from one point to another, but the voltage can.

Comment: That means the current calculated in the video is the same from + to - including the resistance, and it’s just general and if we would add more components it will change according to the change but it will be the same between all components, is what I said correct?

Comment: 1. current flows in a loop - from the + of the power source to the negative of the power source.
Like a chain, each link sees the same 'force'.

Comment: Ahh, ok I think I understand it now, thank you for your answer 

Comment: Yes. The current is the same all around the loop from supply plus, through the resistor to supply minus. That is one of the most basic principles.

Comment: Yep, I’ve actually no experience with this at all, just starting off, because I wanted to build my own circuit boards, but when you mentioned the resistance and @Kartman mentioned the chain and force, so I remembered the water analogy, and that helped , thank you for the clearance, I’m very happy with the help I got 